# Converting a character to another character in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, join, explode, string

I have two arrays one with fake Japanese characters, another with the English alphabet
I have no idea where to go from here, I've tried loops, str_replace, even using the letters array as the keys for the jap array which did work for one word, but I want to break up the words and convert them while including the space.

```
$name = $_POST['engname'];
$name = strtoupper($name);

$jap = array('ka','tu','mi', 'te','ku', 'lu', 'ji', 'ri', 'ki', 'zu', 'me', 'ta', 'rin', 'to', 'mo', 'no', 'ke', 'shi', 'ari', 'chi', 'do', 'ru', 'mei', 'na', 'fu', 'zi');
$letters = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

$names = explode(' ',$name);
$letters = array();
foreach($name as $names) {
$names[] = join('<br/>', str_split($names));
}
echo join('<br/>',$names);
```

Comment: Why did it not work? Was there an error?

Comment: Can you give some example input?

Comment: You do know you have an error there? Should be `foreach($names as $currentname) {`. What do you want to do? Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has a function for that: [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

> `strtr` - Translate characters or replace substrings
>
> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form `array('from' => 'to', ...)`. The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.

```
$name = strtr($name, array_combine($letters, $jap));
```

*(Not sure in which direction you want to go, JAP->ENG or ENG->JAP but from the fact that you use `strtoupper` I assume the latter)*

Comment: Does exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
$name = strtoupper( $_POST['engname'] );

$jap = array('ka','tu','mi', 'te','ku', 'lu', 'ji', 'ri', 'ki', 'zu', 'me', 'ta', 'rin', 'to', 'mo', 'no', 'ke', 'shi', 'ari', 'chi', 'do', 'ru', 'mei', 'na', 'fu', 'zi');
$letters = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

$name = str_replace( $jap , $letters , $name );

echo $name;
```

Comment: I voted up for a quicker way to use the function on the $_POST variable.